# Read json files in pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas

I have large pandas dataframe (17 000 rows) with a filepath in each row associated with a specific json file. For each row I want to read the json file content and extract the content into a new dataframe.

The dataframe looks something like this:

```
                                                       
0      /home/user/processed/config1.json
1      /home/user/processed/config2.json
2      /home/user/processed/config3.json
3      /home/user/processed/config4.json
4      /home/user/processed/config5.json
...                                                  ...
16995  /home/user/processed/config16995.json
16996  /home/user/processed/config16996.json
16997  /home/user/processed/config16997.json
16998  /home/user/processed/config16998.json
16999  /home/user/processed/config16999.json
```

What is the most efficient way to do this?

I believe a simple for-loop might be best suited here?

```
import json
json_content = []

for row in df:
  with open(row) as file:
    json_content.append(json.load(file))

result = pd.DataFrame(json_content)
```

Answer (score 2):

Generally, I'd try with `iterrows()` function (as a first hit to improve efficiency).
Implementation could possibly look like that:

```
import json
import pandas as pd


json_content = []

for row in df.iterrows():
    with open(row) as file:
        json_content.append(json.load(file))

result = pd.Series(json_content)
```

Answer (score 2):

Possible solution is the following:

```
# pip install pandas

import pandas as pd

#convert column with paths to list, where: : - all rows, 0 - first column
paths = df.iloc[:, 0].tolist()

all_dfs = []
for path in paths:
    df = pd.read_json(path, encoding='utf-8')
    all_dfs.append(df)
```

---

Each `df` in `all_dfs` can be accessed individually or in loop by index like `all_dfs[0]`, `all_dfs[1]` and etc.

If you wish you can merge all_dfs into the single dataframe.

```
dfs = df.concat(all_dfs, axis=1)
```